# окно tmux закрывается после выполнения команды

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

Я хочу, чтобы у меня tmux при открытии ssh сеанса сам настраивался и добавлял окна.
Для этого я сделал конфигурационный файл `~/.tmux.conf`, в который поместил команду создания одного окошка:

```
new -n htop 'htop'
```

Все работает, это хорошо. Но если я закрою htop клавишей `Q`, то и окошко закроется, а вместе с ним и сам tmux.

Я нашел способ не закрывать окошко с помощью команды `set -g remain-on-exit on`.
Но в таком случае после закрытия htop'a, мы видим не shell оболочку, а это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае команда htop перестает работать (хотя до `set -g remain-on-exit on` работала) и вместо shell'a пишет Pane is dead, а я хочу shell.

Файл `.tmux.conf`:

```
new -n htop 'htop'
set -g remain-on-exit on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В этом случае команда htop перестает работать (хотя до set -g remain-on-exit on работала) и вместо shell'a пишет Pane is dead, а я хочу shell.

Как-то так:

```
new 'htop; bash'
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, блин, я это пытался сделать пару часов вчера. а ты помог! спасибо